# PostgreSQL dumping bytea data directly to File

Tags: postgresql

I have to dump the content of byte a column to file. Similar to what `MySQL's`

```sql
SELECT ... INTO DUMPFILE` functionality (It works perfectly with checksum match).
```

For `PostgreSQL`. I tried with below query:

```sql
COPY (select binary_field from data_table  WHERE id='1') TO '/tmp/binfile'  WITH (FORMAT binary);
```

The problem is, the file gets created, but the checksum doesn't match with the original file, which was loaded in the database by using function `pg_read_binary_file`.

Currently, I'm using the python psycopg2 module to read the file in bytes and then write in the file (It also matches checksum).

I don't want to read in python and again write. So let me know if how it can be done?

> Postgresql version 10.5

Comment: What checksum? Note that `COPY TO (FORMAT binary)` writes a file that contains a header and trailer. Search for the paragraph `Binary Format` on [this page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-copy.html).

Comment: So basically , I require the exact file I loaded in bytea column, without any header and trailer, how can I do it?

Comment: You'll have to write code for that.

Comment: Currently I'm able to do with python code.. but it some rare case fails with memory error.  In postgresql can't we just dump data like mysql ?